# How to return the a unix-timestamp for the start of a month of a particular unix-timestamp PHP

Tags: php, unix, unix-timestamp

I need a generic function that takes a unix-timestamp representation of a date-time and returns a representation for, say, midnight on the first of the month.

i.e. I pass `1352376093` which represents now (Thu, 08 Nov 2012 12:01:33 GMT) and `1351728000` is returned which represents (Thu, 01 Nov 2012 00:00:00 GMT)

Answer (score 2):

This snippet should help you to solve the problem. Just take only month and year from the existing date and convert it back to the timestamp.

```
<?php
     $time = 1352376093;
     $date = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', $time);
     $result = strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

So ended up with this function:

```
$earliest_issue = db_result( $result, 0 );
$day_of_month_of_earliest_issue = date("d", $earliest_issue);
$hour_of_month_of_earliest_issue = date("h", $earliest_issue);
$minute_of_month_of_earliest_issue = date("i", $earliest_issue);
$seconds_in_month = date("s", $earliest_issue);
$seconds_in_day_of_month = (($day_of_month_of_earliest_issue*24*60*60)-86400);
$seconds_in_hour_of_month = (($hour_of_month_of_earliest_issue*60*60)-3600);
$seconds_in_minute_of_month = (($minute_of_month_of_earliest_issue*60));
$start_time_of_query = ($earliest_issue - $seconds_in_day_of_month - $seconds_in_hour_of_month - $seconds_in_minute_of_month - $seconds_in_month);

return $start_time_of_query;
```

where `$earliest_issue` is the start date...

If anyone reading this has a more elegant function as I had hoped then please contribute, thanks!